# /etc/apparmor.d directory missing

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, apparmor

I am working on an embedded platform which is built using yocto framework.
I can see that the apparmor is enabled in the platform however the directory `/etc/apparmor.d/` is missing.

1. Can anyone point out, as to what is missed in this case?
2. I believe the directory shall be automatically created once the yocto successfully compiles the apparmor from sources.

```
$ cat /sys/module/apparmor/parameters/enabled 
Y
```

P.S. I am mere user of apparmor on this platform and have not integrated it.

Comment: Note that the kernel comes only with the kernel-space part. To have things exposed in userspace (like the config folder in /etc, and install other related binary files), you will need to install the relevant [userspace tools](https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-security/tree/recipes-mac/AppArmor/apparmor_3.1.3.bb?h=master) also.